# Powershell: Filter excel columns and rows dynamically

Tags: excel, powershell

I have an excel document. The columns can be added so I can't use the position such as A/B/C to identify the column. Please the column header can contain spaces.
I'm trying to use powershell + ComObject to manipulate the excel file as later  I might need to create pivot table etc on it. But I stuck at the first step, as to select my desired data.
Here's the **mock code** for what I'm trying to do:

```
    $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $excel.Visible  = $true
    $wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open(".\logs.xlsx")
    $ws = $wb.Sheets.Item("rawLogs") #so far it's fine
    $desiredColumns = "Problem PC","Problem Date","Final Resolution"
    $dateRange = "Jan 2021"
    $dataArray = $ws | where-object {$_.date = $dateRange} | select $desiredColumns
    ...other logic
```

Can you please help with the "filter" part, for the desired columns and rows?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked into dumping excel and just using a csv, json, or some other structure format?

Comment: Are you trying to modify the data in the workbook or just access it?  There is a nice module available called ImportExcel which you can use to read and manipulate excel documents from powershell.  https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.1.0

Comment: I also highly recommend using the ImportExcel module. It has lots of nifty manipulation tools available upon import and export.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback from Colyn1337 Daniel and @general-gouda. Does it meant he comobject doesn't have a good support for the data filtering? I will check the ImportExcel module as you suggested but since later I need to insert charts, Pivoit table etc back to the excel file, i think at which stage I will have to use the comOjbect. It looks a bit clumsy - Manipulate the same file using two set of modules.